# Mapping a json with $ in result for jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Im trying to get some auto complete to work. I have this URL i shoud read my JSON From:

```
http://openscan.addi.dk/2.0/?action=openScan&field=phrase.title&lower=hest&limit=10&outputType=json
```

When i receive the result i try to map it into my jquery autocomplete, i use the following jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            function log(message) {
                $("<div/>").text(message).prependTo("#log");
                $("#log").scrollTop(0);
            }

            $("#search").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://openscan.addi.dk/2.0/?action=openScan&field=phrase.title&lower=hest&limit=10&outputType=json",
                        dataType: "jsonp",

                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data.scanResponse.term, function (item) {
                                return {
                                    label: item.name+' ( '+item.hitCount+')',
                                    value: item.name
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
                },
                minLength: 2,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    log(ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
                },
                open: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
                },
                close: function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
    <h2>
        Demo of autocomplete using OpenScan
    </h2>
    Start typing below.<br />
    <input id="search" />
```

My problem is the result its not like the limited amount of JSON i have seen before, it contains $ and @ for properties, how do I index them?

**Edit**
Changed data.scanResponse to data.scanResponse.term

Comment: There's nothing wrong with those property names; property names can be any string value.  A potential problem is that that site doesn't appear to respond with JSONP - it's just JSON.  Is that your domain name (the domain from which your pages with that code are served)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what are exact values you want to display, but you could access properties using array syntax, like this:

```
label: item.name["@"]+' ( '+item.hitCount["$"]+')'
```